# How to Save and Load by iOS Programming

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an application that I want to have take pictures using a `UIImagePickerController`, then stick said resulting image in a thumbnail view.  But, when you exit the app, I want to re-display the same thumbnail as when the user last left off.  My question is threefold:

1. What is the best way to implement saving and loading the image between app life cycles?
2. How would I go about changing the default shutter sound when the user takes a photo?
3. How can I reset all of the above to some default setting if the user so chooses?

Comment: I do not know how to change the shutter sound of the camera? Shutter sound is iPhone in Japan, even if you silent mode. I'd like to put a silence so erase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying Using Core Data or NSUserDefault..
Some Links get you Started:
1.http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started
2.http://maniacdev.com/2012/03/tutorial-getting-started-with-core-data-in-ios-5-using-xcode-storyboards/
3. Some Code:

```
//Saving:  
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)forKey:key];
//Loading:     
NSData* imageData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:key];
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Comment: NO NO NO.  Do NOT ever put NSData in a plist.  Bad evil not objective c things will happen.

Comment: You link to two core data articles, but you provided an example using NSUserDefaults.  Why?

Comment: I prefer Core Data over NSUserDefault, but if you need to save something simple use NSUserDefault :)…

Comment: @Programmer... Core Data and NSUserDefaults have very different purposes. As does writing files to the app's sandbox or writing to a plist. Use each for their intended purposes.

Comment: @CodaFi Why not? I've done it fine plenty of times. It's also the preferred way of storing objects (by conforming to the `NSCoding` protocol> per the documentation on `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: The problem with your logic is that data from images is not simple in the least.  You're cramming potentially megabytes of data into a key-value store uncompressed, which makes access (the thing dictionaries were designed for in the first place), both slow, and unpredictable.  Besides, what would happen if you tried to save data that was outside the character range of the plist?  Congratulations, your file is now corrupted.  Seriously, just write the data to a file, then save it's path to defaults.

Comment: Thanks everyone, many things have been told me.I'll try to learn a little more CoreData!

Comment: 1) The OP is storing a thumbnail image in `NSUserDefaults`; a 100x100 image is like 4 kilobytes. 2) Even if it was bad to save images to `NSUserDefaults`, you can't go around saying "Do NOT ever put NSData in a plist" because `NSData` is used to save objects using `<NSCoding>`. To the OP, CoreData really isn't the tool for this. If you aren't using `NSUserDefaults`, then you should probably save to a file instead. CoreData is about saving large quantities of information in a database and is too complex for the need to save a single image.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do at delegate you just save your image locally(I usually prefer sqlite) and when you start your app you just need to execute a select query to check whether the image exist or not and if it is, then just check which is latest one(or the case which you want to pick up).

Hope, it'll give you working idea.

In any concern, let me informed. :)

Comment: Why put images in the database? Just write them to a folder in the app's sandbox.

Comment: yeah, you can write them into the file and again read.This is up-to you.But my concern is that since you'll do write/read operation it'll take time in process as much I think.

Answer (score 0):

Either you save the image data to `NSUserDefaults` (as metioned by others) or your app's sandbox, or you might as well save the image to the device's camera roll in the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` delegate like so:

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];  
//Block Request to save the image to camera roll  
[library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){  
    if (error) {  
        NSLog(@"Error saving to Albums");  
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Saved Image Url %@", assetURL);
    }  
}];  
[library release];
```

The delegate `- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info` info dictionary object then has the image url for the key `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` which you can then use to fetch the image, again using [ALAssetsLibrary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html). HTH.